# OS/Windows Internals Videos

Tags: windows, windows-7, internals

I know about the Windows Internals book by Russinovich. But I'm looking for someething along the same lines but that is video/audio.

are there any videos for learning O.S/Windows  Internals ?

Comment: Though I understand why this question is off-topic, it was helpful to me. You may also want to check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/learn/webcasts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some great videos on Channel 9 starring Mark Russinovich, even.

- [Mark Russinovich on Windows 7](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Mark-Russinovich-Inside-Windows-7/)
- [Mark Russinovich on Windows 7 - Part 2](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Mark-Russinovich-Inside-Windows-7-Redux/)
- [Landy Wang on the NT Memory Manager](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Landy-Wang-Windows-Memory-Manager/)